# How can I extract all archives in the current folder using command-line 7-zip, without running the 7z command multiple times?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, archiving

How can I extract all archives in the current folder using command-line 7-zip, without running the 7z command multiple times? Running it multiple times seems inefficient, and requires slightly different solutions for different shells/operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `7z x "*"`. The quotes are required. Note that this will extract recursively. I'm not sure how to run it non-recursively, but as a workaround you can create a new directory and move the files there first.